# HTTP2: Should inner service apis use http2

Tags: node.js, http, ssl, microservices, http2

I'm using a Microservice architecture, where one service calls multiple services at a time with servers on nodejs

I was planning to use HTTP2 for API calls from one service to another, as it makes use of just one TCP connection with header compression.

However, HTTP2 needs TLS support, which implies a TLS handshake for every API call made by service to others, adding overhead roundtrips.

Although TLS1.3 takes only one round trip, still it adds up some extra overhead time.

My question is, Is it a good idea to use HTTP2 in the first place for API calls from one service to another, or it's better to continue with HTTP1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP2 most likely won't be more performant than ordinary HTTP1.1. It's only faster when you compare them in the context of HTTPS and parallel requests. HTTP2 allows to re-use the same TLS handshake, as well as use the same connection for multiple *parallel* requests (multiplex).

This is the reason you wouldn't set up [HTTP2 between nginx and your app server](https://youtu.be/4OiyssTW4BA?t=927) - as you usually don't need TLS between them. So unless a) you need a secure connection between your services and b) you're planning to issue parallel requests - it doesn't seem to make sense to use HTTP2 for service-to-service communication.

PS: also read the answer by @sbordet - there seem to be use cases when HTTP2 can be beneficial even without TLS.

Comment: actually, I have a scenario in which I need to use http2 in order to upload a file from a Browser and later receive progress updates on the same connection. The browser should talk with the Apache Proxy in SSL + HTTP2, and the Apache is supposed to reverse proxy the request to Node, stripping the TLS but maintaining the HTTP2

Answer (score 4):

HTTP/2 does not require TLS support.

It just so happen that all browser vendors (and only them) decided to not support clear-text HTTP/2, but other clients such as `curl`, or Java clients, etc. do support clear-text HTTP/2.

However, for server-to-server communication, it is possible to use clear-text HTTP/2, and in fact this is a very common deployment.

It is also unfortunate that popular servers that are used as reverse-proxies or load balancers do not support invoking the back-end using HTTP/2, but that's just an implementation limitation.

[HAProxy](https://haproxy.org), for example, allows to offload TLS and then invoke the back-end with clear-text HTTP/2.

If you receive many multiplexed requests on the front-end, you can leverage HTTP/2 multiplexing towards the back-end, saving a lot of resources.
A web page that requests say 30 multiplexed resources to the front-end will need to open or otherwise use 30 different connections to the back-end when using HTTP/1 (or less connections and be less efficient), versus using just 1 when using HTTP/2.
When using HTTP/2 towards the back-end, you are not limited to just 1 connection, exactly like you are not limited to use only 6 connections when using HTTP/1 (these are just browser limits and do not apply to server-to-server communication).

Furthermore, back-end applications that use HTTP/2 features such as HTTP/2 push (albeit now being phased out) would work transparently using pure HTTP/2 communication, while won't be able to use the HTTP/2 features when using HTTP/1 communication towards the back-end.
This is true for any other HTTP/2 feature such as PING frames, SETTINGS frames, etc. all of which are lost when communicating to the back-end application when using HTTP/1.

From the resources point of view, a smart reverse-proxy or load balancer can just offload TLS, and then blindly forward the HTTP/2 clear-text bytes to the back-end -- no need to interpret the bytes in either direction.
There would be no need to parse the HTTP/2 request, convert it to the HTTP/1 format and viceversa when receiving the HTTP/1 response (from HTTP/1 to HTTP/2).
This causes unnecessary CPU burning and TCP connection usage.

So, in principles HTTP/2 towards the back-end is very desirable.

I have worked with clustered systems where HTTP/2 for server-to-server communication was a huge benefit just for the many less resources used across the whole cluster.

The reality, however, is that the most popular front-end servers do not support HTTP/2 towards the back-end (mostly for non-technical reasons), so most of the times you just have to give up and deploy sub-optimal systems.

Comment: _I have worked with clustered systems where HTTP/2 for server-to-server communication was a huge benefit just for the many less resources used across the whole cluster._ - could you publish your findings and the settings used in both scenarios?

Comment: I can't publish the numbers, but the cluster was of  type "every node connects to every node" kind of cluster. So every node had N incoming and N outgoing. For HTTP/1 you want to have some parallelism, so multiply those by M, while for HTTP/2 you rely on multiplexing. The HTTP/2 system was using a factor M less connections, which translates to less load the I/O both at the OS level and at the JVM level (yes using Java), which led to much reduced latencies, etc. -- a cascade of benefits. Sure it's not a common use case, but shows how HTTP/2 in server-to-server is desirable.

Comment: _a factor M less connections, which translates to less load the I/O both at the OS level and at the JVM level_ - what was this load related to? I mean, having M connections by itself shouldn't add additional traffic (except for initial handshakes and then keep alives). And instead of OS doing TCP/IP routing your App Server will do the multiplexing logic, so doesn't seem like you win here either. As for the content itself, while HTTP2 compresses some of it due to binary nature, it also adds extra headers again to support multiplexing.

Comment: It's not only about the network traffic. It's about the number of connections. Having to manage NxM connections for HTTP/1 and only N for HTTP/2 (or Nxm, where m << M) leads to less resources being used, so more efficient I/O, compound with less network traffic, which in turn leads to better thread utilization, less latencies, etc. for a cascading effect of benefits. HTTP/2 does not add any extra header to support multiplexing.

Comment: is there any working example for Node serving HTTP2 requests without TLS? none of these seem to work (client is curl/7.88.1 )